# Always getting DependencyProperty.unsetvalue

Tags: wpf, multibinding

So am testing multibinding in wpf and i have three text boxes which should get the year,month,day and my converter class should return a date with those inputs..pretty simple.

But in my convert method the `values[0]` is always unset that is i am always getting `Dependencyproperty.UnsetValue` even if get give it an initial value.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MultiBinding Demo" Width="200" Height="200">
<Window.Resources>
    <src:DateConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>

    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox Name="tb1" Margin="10"  Width="Auto" Height="20"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="tb2" Margin="10" Width="20" Height="20" ></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="tb3" Width="20" Height="20" ></TextBox>

    <Label Name="Date" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5" >
        <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                <Binding ElementName="tbl" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="tb2" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="tb3" Path="Text" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

DATECONVERTER CLASS

```
    class DateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values[2] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
           return "";
        }
        else
        {
            int year = (int)values[0];
            int month = (int)values[1];
            int day = (int)values[2];
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
            return date.ToShortDateString();
        }

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it only `values[0]` that is unset, or all three? Also, is this only happening when the view initially loads or does changing the value of the textbox(es) pass the proper values to the converter?

Comment: It looks like it is not reading values[0] value because I put a break point on the return statements in converter class and it is hit on onload and when i editing value[1] and value[2] text boxes but not value[0]. This will explain the dependencyproperty.unsetValue error so, the question is why is it not reading the first value in the values array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at your XAML, and it looks like your first TextBox is named `tb1` (number 1) but in the binding you're referencing element name `tbl` (letter L).

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but now am getting a XamlParseException on the set property on of the label.Content. It seems to be complaining about my cast, I thought it is legal to cast an object to an int?

Comment: `TextBox.Text` is always a `System.String` and you cannot cast that value to a `System.Int32` explicitly. Even though `values` is an array of objects, the values are boxed resulting in the cast exception. You should be using `Int32.TryParse` or possibly one of the `Convert.ToInt32(...)` overloads to get the values from the array.

Comment: Thanks crazyarabian, i used the Int32.TryParse and it worked.